# Unable to Type and update state of input element in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a text box and on typing a name i get a list of options via an api call. I then populate a list and on click of a list item i am trying to fill the text in the input box. Firstly when i add a value prop to the input element i am unable to to type anything in the text box. Also on clicking the list item the value of the text doesnt update. Can someone tell me what im doing wrong here

```
class AutoCompleteSearch extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: '',
      suggestions: []
    }
  }

  autoSearchInputChange(e) {
    let searchValue = e.target.value;
    if (!searchValue.trim()) {
      this.setState({ value : '', suggestions: [] })
      return ;
    }

    if (searchValue.length >= 3) {
      setTimeout(() => {
      searchDoctorByName(searchValue).then((response) => {
        this.setState({ value : searchValue, suggestions: response.data })
      })}, 1000);
    }
  }

  selectItemFromList(doctorObject) {
    this.setState({
      value: doctorObject.name ,
      suggestions: [doctorObject]
    });
  console.log(this.state);
}

render() {
  let renderItems = () => {
    let listItems = this.state.suggestions.map((suggestion, index) => {
      let doctorObject = suggestion;
        return (
          <li onClick={() => this.selectItemFromList(doctorObject)} key={index}>
          {doctorObject.name}
          </li>
          );
      });
    return (
      <div>
      <ul className="doctor-list">
      {listItems}
      </ul>
      </div>
    );

  }

    return (
        <div className="form-group">
        <label className="control-label form-label col-md-4" htmlFor="auto-complete-search">Doctor Name</label>
        <div className="col-md-20">
          <input className="custom-input"type="text" ref="test" id="auto-complete-search" required
          placeholder="Enter Doctor name"
          onChange={(e) => this.autoSearchInputChange(e)}
          />
            {this.state.suggestions.length > 0 ? renderItems() : null}

        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AutoCompleteSearch;
```

Comment: Why are you using `setTimeout`?

Comment: Was testing something.. Want to throttle the api call..

Comment: You want value to be set in Input ?

Comment: Yes..also i am unable to type anything in the input box. But when i remove the value prop then im able to type but then the value doesnt get set in the input

Comment: @NitishPhanse protip: don't use setTimeout, use a network throttler that you can set to "3g", "56k modem", "1mbps" etc with a simple dropdown =)

Comment: All right got the solution.. The on change handler **has** to have a setState method with the concerned value being set to e.target.value.